# How can I add the same resistance to two resistors?

Tags: operational-amplifier, potentiometer

I have a resistor and a capacitor in series, connected in series to a parallel capacitor and resistor (there is an error with uploading the picture of it)

```
                    R1         C1          R2
                                    ____/\/\/\/\--|
(op amp leg) ------/\/\/\/\---||---|              |-------(ground)
                                   |_______||_____|
                                      c2   ||
```

I want to add a potentiometer, such that I add the same resistance to both resistors.
How is it possible?

Comment: CircuitLab / Imgur is out of action today.

Answer (score 2):

Use a dual-gang potentiometer. These are popular in audio circuitry for controlling stereo audio channels.

Or, you can use two independent digital pots and control them in sync.

Comment: Thank you. 
Do you know where to find it in Multisim?

Comment: @Almog I do not. You may have to roll your own with functions or mathematics.